# How to add a margin to a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have so far a simple python tkinter window and i'm adding text, buttons, etc.

snippet:

```
class Cfrm(Frame):

    def createWidgets(self):

        self.text = Text(self, width=50, height=10)
        self.text.insert('1.0', 'some text will be here')
        self.text.tag_configure('big', font=('Verdana', 24, 'bold'))


        self.text["state"] = "disabled"
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.quitw = Button(self)
        self.quitw["text"] = "exit",
        self.quitw["command"] = self.quit
        self.quitw.grid(row=1, column=1)


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
```

the problem is, I want to have about a 15-20 px margin around the window, I looked everywhere, and I couldn't find a solution. Also

```
self.text.tag_configure('big', font=('Verdana', 24, 'bold'))
```

doesn't work. Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution I found for question 1:

```
self.grid(padx=20, pady=20)
```

Removing `.text` seems to change the whole frame. I still haven't solved problem 2.

Answer (score 16):

Use the pad options (padx, pady, ipadx, ipady) for the grid command to add padding around the text widget. For example:

```
self.text.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
```

If you want padding around the whole GUI, add padding when you pack the application frame:

```
self.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
```

When you say the tag command doesn't work, how do you define "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Does the font look big but not bold, bold but not big, ...? The command looks fine to me, and when I run it it works fine.

Your example doesn't show that you're actually applying that tag to a range of text. Are you? If so, how? If you do the following, what happens?

```
self.text.insert("1.0", 'is this bold?', 'big')
```

Comment: when I do: self.text.insert(1.0, 'is this bold?', 'big')
absolutely nothing changes.The text shows up, but no bold

Padx, Pady does work, the only problem is that it adds a padding for the widget, and not the whole window, so there is now space between the text and the button. Would it be possible to do something like resize the window relative to it's current size?

Comment: self.pack(padx...) is super helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You can add an innerFrame with some borderwidth or ipadx,ipady attributes to the root Tk() object. Then put everything in it. And to be sure that innerFrame's width and height values are as the window's, use fill and expand attributes.

```
root = tk.Tk()
innerFrame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=25, bg="red")
innerFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

someButton = tk.Button(innerFrame, text="Button1")
someButton.pack()
```

or

```
root = tk.Tk()
innerFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="red")
innerFrame.pack(ipadx=15, ipady=15, fill="both", expand=True)

someButton = tk.Button(innerFrame, text="Button1")
someButton.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do it is adjust your relief style to flat, then you only have to adjust your border width.

```
self.Border = Tkinter.Frame(self, relief='flat', borderwidth=4)
```