# tkinter labels dont show

Tags: python, tkinter, label

So I got the assignment to make a small Bingo App (Windows btw) after I followed a few webinars on Tkinter GUI and some Googling.

I have made successfull little apps that worked correctly, but this time I try to make it with knowledge I think I have.

Anyway, in that Bingo app, I want 50 labels that represent 50 numbers of the Bingo card, 5 rows of 10 numbers.
I know how to align them, but they need to show up first.

Can you look at my code and assess what I do wrong?

Ignore the many Dutch comments :)

```
    '''
      iWMMMM0.
    XM#o:..iIMM.
   MM. :XC17, YM8
  M@ v@9.  .W# ,M,
 #M 7@i ,0$: M0 MM
.M. @7  M@t, ME MQ
MM iM.  #$Ci$Q ;M#CCY:.
CM ,M,   b#$;  v;7IEW@MMM@1
 MQ WQ    .tE0Q2nCCYc;i,:7#MMi
 :M  @b  .    ..   .:YCb0U: YMM.
  WM  E@i ....  ,i:      ,b#; bMQ,SbW06i
   oM  MC ...  MME9#$Y .   .#b SM@b2tob@MM1
    Mi @7 ... @M .v iMt ...  @X  :CoUzt: :MM,         nWM@Bc    :nQ#$Ui
    M: @Y ..  M9 MM@ b# ...  Zb1#Zi. .;Z#Y SMi      MM#t;vCMM,CMM0C77bMM8
    M, @7 ..  @6 Y7 ;Mn ...  #QB.       ,#b ZM     MM .n9U; bMM. ;z2U7  MM
    M: @Y .,  @9.;tQQv ...  ;MQ,         :@; Mv   MM X$:  M; , ;$2.  7@i M8
    M: @7 ..  #BW1i   ..,:Y$Mt$           MX MMtiEM: E@: ZME,.W$c  ;  c@ .M
    M: @Y .,  ME   ..   .ZMM8o89         QM. i;U@@ .Zb7:   ,BBYzQ bM@  Mi M
    Mi @X ..  M, iMM@WS     :bWQb,     ,#M1;IoIX  1@c bMMX  iM I@E$CM  M, M
  .MM  @7 .,  Mn EM8AEE#: .   v$AWQ#$Q#MMIWz,  ;$Z$  MMzW2  M@  $ZY$C bM CM
  MZ ib@i ..  @@. ;t  $z@. .,  CWUWnE$b7:  :Y   #$c  MEYY .MM8   :;  vM. M1
 iM iMi  ..,  #bWI,..M@i#C ..,  Mv  i#E.  UMM2  @BC   oC;tMMCES    .@M  MM
  MY E0   ... S@i:Z$MZ .Mv ...  M8  7WEz  MnZo  @obUA:   ic.7bEW$#M@C iMM
  CMi I@;  ..  b#;     $$  ... ,MQ  7$Zz  @zbz  @IXW#E69z.   80  ::iAMM;
   iM$ .$Qi  .  :Z$Q0Q#6. ...  MQ0  C$b1  MtQ7  YZWW,.c$@@   MC MMM@b.
     MM7 iBWv.     ..,       .M#7$  v$8;  vQ0:iCAM: :#bM0  nMU BM
      :MM1 .6$Q7:          ;MMS:Q7   @#i12EMzEESB#  .7:,,2M@  MM
        ,MM#: ,1E$BQbZ6EBMM@;  iQQ@@B$72n7i.,vo  tQQIZQ$WC .#MQ
           6MM@o;,,:ivY;i,,iEMM...,,:iC2Q#MMMQ$M$..,i::,;9MMZ
               YIEbEAU269086, ;Bb08bAz;:.       7QbEZb8boi
'''

##Basale geimporteerde functies
from tkinter import*
#self=()
#Importeert de randomfucntie
#import random
#Importeert de Python Debugger
#Runnen met pdb.run
#import pdb
#Importeert de PIL Python Image Library
#from PIL import Image, ImageTK
#image = image.open("bestandsnaam.jpg")
#photo  ImageTK.PhotoImage(image)
#Een afbeelding op een label
#label = Label(image=photo(als photo de naam van de variable is))
#label.image = photo (bewaren als referentie?<- geen idee nog)


'''
#=# Start van metainfo class/klasse
class MetaBingPy():

    def __init__(self):
        super(MetaBingPy, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()
        MetaBingPy.BingoPyC(self)
##Functie voor random number generator

def BingoPyC:
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.title("Python Bingo")

#=#Einde metainfo class
'''



###def random.randint(1,50)
#####of# randrange(1,50)

##GUI voor BingPy, moet root heten. Geen eigen naam, zoals:
##BingPyGUI wat ik had.
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Bingo Python")
root.wm_maxsize("800","600")
root.wm_minsize("800","600")
#root.wm_grid(baseWidth="800", baseHeight="800")

#root.grid("800x800")
#_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm grid window ?baseWidth baseHeight
#widthInc heightInc?"
##self.title="Bingo Python"
###GUI voor BingPy code, altijd afsluiten met:
###bovenaan
root.mainloop()



'''
#Algemene Python Bingo klasse
class BingoPy

def

'''



#Labels voor alle nummers (50)

label1 = Label(root, text="1jghjgjkhjhg")
label1.grid()
label1.pack()

label2 = Label(root, text="2")
label2.grid()
label2.pack()

label3 = Label(root, text="3")
label3.grid()
label3.pack()

label4 = Label(root, text="4")
label4.grid()
label4.pack()

label5 = Label(root, text="5")
label5.grid()
label5.pack()

label6 = Label(root, text="6")
label6.grid()
label6.pack()

label7 = Label(root, text="7")
label7.grid()
label7.pack()

label8 = Label(root, text="8")
label8.grid()
label8.pack()

label9 = Label(root, text="9")
label9.grid()
label9.pack()

label10 = Label(root, text="10")
label10.grid()
label10.pack()

label11 = Label(root, text="11")
label11.grid()
label11.pack()

label12 = Label(root, text="12")
label12.grid()
label12.pack()

Label13 = Label(root, text="13")
Label13.grid()
Label13.pack()

label14 = Label(root, text="14")
label14.grid()
label14.pack()

label15 = Label(root, text="15")
label15.grid()
label15.pack()

label16 = Label(root, text="16")
label16.grid()
label16.pack()

label7 = Label(root, text="17")
label17.grid()
label17.pack()

label18 = Label(root, text="18")
label18.grid()
label18.pack()

label19 = Label(root, text="19")
label19.grid()
label19.pack()

label20 = Label(root, text="20")
label20.grid()
label20.pack()

label21 = Label(root, text="21")
label21.grid()
label21.pack()

label22 = Label(root, text='22')
label22.grid()
label22.pack()

label23 = Label(root, text="23")
label23.grid()
label23.pack()

label24 = Label(root, text="24")
label24.grid()
label24.pack()

label25 = Label(root, text="25")
label25.grid()
label25.pack()

label26 = Label(root, text="26")
label26.grid()
label26.pack()

label27 = Label(root, text="27")
label27.grid()
label27.pack()

label28.Label(root, text="28")
label28.grid()
label28.pack()

label29 = Label(root, text="29")
label29.grid()
label29.pack()

label30 = Label(root, text="30")
label30.grid()
label30.pack()

label31 = Label(root, text="31")
label31.grid()
label31.pack()

label32 = Label(root, text="32")
label32.grid()
label32.pack()

label33 = Label(root, text="33")
label33.grid()
label33.pack()

label34 = Label(root, text="34")
label34.grid()
label34.pack()

label35 = Label(root, text="35")
label35.grid()
label35.pack()

label36 = Label(root, text="36")
label36.grid()
label36.pack()

label37 = Label(root, text="37")
label37.grid()
label37.pack()

label38 = Label(root, text="38")
label38.grid()
label38.pack()

label39 = Label(root, text="39")
label39.grid()
label39.pack()

label40 = Label(root, text="40")
label40.grid()
label40.pack()

label41 = Label(root, text="41")
label41.grid()
label41.pack()

label42 = Label(root, text="42")
label42.grid()
label42.pack()

label43 = Label(root, text="43")
label43.grid()
label43.pack()

label44 = Label(root, text="44")
label44.grid()
label44.pack()

label45 = Label(root, text="45")
label45.grid()
label45.pack()

label46 = Label(root, text="46")
label46.grid()
label46.pack()

label47 = Label(root, text="47")
label47.grid()
label47.pack()

label48 = Label(root, text="48")
label48.grid()
label48.pack()

label49 = Label(root, text="49")
label49.grid()
label49.pack()

label50 = Label(root, text="50")
label50.grid()
label50.pack()



#Maakt het rood (en als het mogelijk is: doorstrepen) als het getrokken is

#Waarde-return in veld + niet meer zelfde nummer kunnen kiezen


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Knoppen voor afsluiten en nieuw getal

##Afsluiten
#def bingoclose():
#    print("Bingo Afsluiten")
'''
bAfsluiten = Button(root,text"Sluit Bingo Af")
bAfsluiten.pack()
'''

'''
{
'title' : ['BingPy'],
'summary' : ['Simple Bingo Python Application with rand.num generator'],
'authors' : ['Thomas']
#'date' : ['2015']
'base_url' : ['http://www.rainydays.eu']
}

'''

'''
Info en weblinks:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#module-random
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf (Python 2.7!)
https://wiki.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/images/4/41/Pwcgui.pdf
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643235/how-to-add-a-margin-to-a-tkinter
-window Margins in Python (padx, pady)

'''
```

Comment: For easier and faster understading of your code, please remove all the comments and the commented parts. As you can see, you have to scroll a lot until you see some 'usefull' code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to learn about data structures, like `list`.
2. You had `root.mainloop()` early on in the code. That starts a loop. Nothing after that is executed until the window is closed, which means it has to be at the end.
3. Choose one geometry manager. You can't use both `grid()` and `pack()` in the same parent widget, much less on the same child widget.
4. You had some typos, like `label7 =` instead of `label17 =`, and `label28.Label` instead of `label28 = Label`. Most of these would never have happened if you had used a `list`.
5. Obviously, 50 labels won't fit in a single column in a window of that size. You've got some decisions ahead of you involving window size, label placement, possible scrollbar, and so on.

The resulting code taking into account all these points (except the last) is shown below.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Bingo Python")
root.wm_maxsize("800","600")
root.wm_minsize("800","600")

labels = [Label(root, text=i) for i in range(1, 51)]
for label in labels:
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, grid and the amount of labels was indeed screwing up.
I slightly ajusted your in range amount to 1,11 / 12,21, to accomplish my need.
Thank you very much ! :) 

Still learning to use SO but I have rated this comment