# Embedding matplotlib into tkinter canvas opens two windows

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, canvas, tkinter

The following code I am working on in not behaving the way I wish it to. I have embedded a matplotlib graph into a tkinter canvas. The program opens up two windows, one of which functions properly, and one of which is not necessary.I am not sure how to fix this. Here is the code, please ignore the unnecessary imports :)

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import random
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import matplotlib.colors
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

DEBUG_MODE = False                          #Debug mode - True = ON
MATRIX_WIDTH = 50
MATRIX_HEIGHT = 50
WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
LED_COUNT = MATRIX_WIDTH * MATRIX_HEIGHT
REFRESH_RATE = 30                           #REFRESH_RATE used to control FuncAnimation interval
MATRIX = random((50,50))                    #Fills MATRIX as not to be null for first print  


plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'            #Disables matplotlib toolbar
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))             #'figsize' measured in inches
im = plt.imshow(MATRIX, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.Spectral)
plt.axis('off')                             #Turns off x, y axis

def data_gen():                             #Generates amd populates MATRIX with pattern data
    while True:        
        MATRIX = random((MATRIX_WIDTH, MATRIX_HEIGHT))
        yield MATRIX
        if (DEBUG_MODE): print("MATRIX yeilded")

def update(data):                           #Updates/prints new MATRIX from data_gen()
    im.set_array(data)
    if (DEBUG_MODE): print("Updated data")



root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root,text="Matrix Program").grid(column=0, row=0)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=1)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=REFRESH_RATE)
plt.show()
```

What needs to be done to this code so that it opens only one canvas from tkinter with the live matplotlib graph embedded?

How can I set the size of the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call `plt.show()` if you want to show your figure inside a tk GUI. Best do not use `pyplot` at all when embedding.

On the other hand, you probably want to start the mainloop, `tk.mainloop()`, at some point.

Refer to the [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) on how to embedd a matplotlib figure into tk.

Comment: Thanks! If you recommend not using pyplot at all for embedding, what would you recommend to achieve the same result?

Comment: Did you read the example? It doesn't use pyplot either. If you don't even import pyplot you cannot run into problems from attempting to use it.

Comment: Also, any pointers as to how I can set the canvas size in this instance?

Comment: The canvas size is determined by the figure size.

Comment: What if I wanted the figure in the center of the canvas and a space of 100 pixels surrounding the figure?

Comment: This is not a help-desk. Googling reveals e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643235/how-to-add-a-margin-to-a-tkinter-window).